# Relation between drag and aspect ratio

Tags: aerodynamics, commercial-aviation

How does increasing the aspect ratio decrease the drag over the wings? Wouldn't the various types of drag affect over the wings in proportion to the increasing aspect ratio?

Comment: Related: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/5047/how-does-chord-length-affect-wing-design/5056?s=1|0.2328#5056 and especially http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/716/what-dictates-the-aspect-ratio-of-an-aircrafts-wing/8797#8797

Comment: I think the later is related so much that it can be considered duplicate.