# Why don't solar powered aircraft use wings with more surface area

Tags: aircraft-design, solar-power

I was looking at some solar aviation projects, and I noticed they appear to follow the designs of a glider.

[image]

The Helios drone above is basically a flying wing with a high aspect ratio.

[image]

And the solar impulse above is a textbook glider with minimal cord length and a long wing span.

I understand the idea is a wing with a high aspect ratio reduces parasitic drag by decreasing its surface area, however in this case don't you want the most wing surface area possible?

[This answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/8797/31421) shows that induced drag is unaffected by the wings aspect ratio, so if it's only parasitic drag we're trying to combat here, why not keep the wing span the same, but make it's cord longer?

Won't the added solar panels you could fit on a wing make up for any friction drag caused by the longer cord?

Taking this to the extreme could you make some kind of solar powered rectangle that has a width (span) comparable to the gliders above, but a length (cord) twice as long as the span?

Surely you'll have enough power to make the aircraft fly, so are there other design considerations that factor in when choosing the cord length of these solar powered projects?

Comment: The question seems to be downplaying the importance of parasitic drag.  The root of the question seems to be  "why doesn't the desire for maximum surface area for solar collection drive the design of solar-powered aircraft toward a lower aspect ratio than we see in practice."

Comment: @quietflyer yes I think you could summarize my question as such, but how much of a role does parasitic drag really play? Considering solar panels can provide ~1kw per square meter isn't that enough power to compensate for the added drag?

Comment: It's an interesting question-- consider the Solar Impulse-- they could collect enough power to fully charge the batteries after a night of slowly-descending gliding-- it's not clear how more chord would have helped them-- the wing loading was already very low and more chord might have had unacceptable consequences in turbulence and more batteries might have been needed to benefit from the extra cells-- anyway it is a good question and I'm not sure I have a specific suggestion for improvement here.

Comment: @quietflyer actually your mention of batteries might explain it. It's not so really how much power these planes can produce in full sun, but the performance of the aircraft when flying at night on batteries. Batteries are heavy, and I think these projects are more about all round performance, than just daytime.

Comment: It is not clear to me what is your main question here. Do you want to know why your "flying rectangle" is a bad idea? Or just what are the drivers for the aspect ratio chosen for these projects? It does seem like you understand the role of aspect ratio in the drag equation, so if your question is the first one, could you edit the rest out?

Comment: @AEhere I'm asking why we've never seen a "flying rectangle" in solar projects. I included the 2 projects I did as references to show how solar aviation is typically designed, but can remove them if you think it's too much. In the comments above it was discussed how nighttime flying may play a role in why rectangles have never been designed, but if you have any more input I'd like to hear it.

Comment: My input is that the flying rectangle still needs to fly like an airplane, as solar panels don´t generate enough power to power a TWR>1 craft. Therefore the approach is the same as with gliders, where the span is limited by structural requirements and the chord is limited by the need for a decent aspect ratio. I´ll try spinning this into an actual answer if nobody (read: the glider enthusiasts around here) beats me to it.

Comment: @AEhere I'd love to read a real answer about this. Solar panels produce ~1kw of power per square meter, that seems like more than enough to counter parasitic drag, and the few pounds of weight the panels would add. I understand you'd need a longish span to keep the induced drag reasonable, but I don't see anything stopping it. However I'll admit I'm not an expert at running numbers either.

Comment: *"Solar panels produce ~1kw of power per square meter"* didn´t notice that before... are you sure? Sounds way too optimistic. A quick search point to 1kW as the *input solar power per square meter on the ground*, after the 20% or so efficiency you´re likely to get, that's 200W per square meter. Napkin math: an $11m^2$ ASH 26 motor glider would gain about 2.2kW... well short of the 37kW its real engine produces.

Comment: @AEhere Quick google search and you are definitely correct. I was thinking how much sun energy hits per square meter, but solar panels are obviously not near 100%. Sorry for that. However I think the idea still has merit, as the sun seeker duo claims steady flight with 7hp (5kwh), but yeah it makes the margins a lot tighter, and the craft will fly much slower.

Comment: @YAHsaves Solar Impulse 2 comes in at 245 Watt/square meter.  But it can generate 50 kW with its four motors to lift over 5000 lbs.  The wing area is 269 meters squared.  So look at that RB-57 as a design possibility.  Remember AR factor is only added to CDo, and lengthening chord may provide benefits in this case.  But it must glide well enough to survive the night.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni how is the Canberra relevant? I know it looks like it has a large chord, but it is a totally different class, and with a wing loading of $175kg/m^2$ it is hardly comparable to electric craft like the Solar Impulse, with a wing loading under $10kg/m^2$. I am more inclined to think the Canberra had a large root chord to deal with the combination of early jet engines and thin airfoil.

Comment: It is the NASA R "arrrrr" B - 57.  That and some writings show that increasing chord may be viable.  The RB-57 can fly very high.  It's the wing.  So we change jets to props and lighten it up...the design still goes high.  They actually did this with the B-36 "featherweight" (reduce weight).  Shame only 4 have survived.  This concept may have legs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, because solar panels are pretty mediocre sources of power per area. An industry average found via quick Google search is in the 200 - 300 Watt per square meter range, so let us be very optimistic and take the higher value, $300W/m^2$, for a round of math. If you want the details, solar irradiation on the surface is about $1kW/m^2$ and the best experimental photo-voltaic cell efficiencies by year are graphed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photovoltaics#/media/File:Best_Research-Cell_Efficiencies.png).

Using the [ASH 26](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schleicher_ASH_26) motor glider as a case study, we can see if solar powering an aircraft is as trivial as the OP suggests.

Assuming our panels are made of fairy dust we can further decide their weight is negligible and that we can perfectly cover the $11.68\,m^2$ of wing area this glider has and that it will operate as though under normal incidence (Sun at 90° to the panel) all the time. Thus, $3.5\,kW$ of free energy... which sadly is only $9.4\,\%$ of the power supplied by the Wankel engine used on the real glider, and with which it attains a very humble $4\,m/s$ climb rate. This is before even considering that batteries are also very inefficient sources of energy per unit of mass when compared to hydrocarbons.

---

Now, for the second part of the OP´s query, how about enlarging the chord of the wing to increase the area?
This also happens to fall flat for different reasons. The drag coefficient:
$$
C_D =C_{D0} + \frac{(C_L)^2}{\pi e AR}
$$
has the aspect ratio ($AR = {b^2 \over S}$) of the wing in the denominator of the second term, the so called induced drag (because it is induced by the lift, note the coefficient of lift itself appears in the numerator).

This equation quickly illustrates why gliders have long wings: a higher AR provides a lower induced drag term. The other term, the parasitic drag, is either indifferent to the chord or slowly grows with it due to boundary layer transition in laminar airfoil designs.

We can arrive at the conclusion that for a given surface, a higher-AR wing will be the less draggy solution.

Therefore, the current attempts at solar powered aircraft all attempt to add area by extending the wings, and are limited by structural constraints like bending moment at the root, which you can clearly see them try and alleviate by spacing out the engines into the wings, providing some relief at the expense of increased roll inertia.

Comment: “200 - 300W range”: 300 Watt per elefant? Or per potato? Or?

Comment: @JanHudec I deserved that sass. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you for drawing this out on paper, it helps to see the numbers. One thing I didn't understand though, is I mentioned in my question how the induced drag doesn't actually increase with cord length. Are you suggesting the answer I linked to is incorrect?

Comment: @Peter Kämpf tends to be right so listen to him. Maybe II can make the answer clearer... or maybe I´m wrong and need to go back to school. Do note that Peter's calculation is for two wings of the same *span*, so he can allow one to have twice the surface of the other. Since span and area are the usual variables that are set by outside requirements, that approach makes a lot of sense. If you want to compare two wins of the same surface area, things change.

Comment: Note that intensity of Sun light is around $1\ \mathrm{kW}\cdot\mathrm{m}^{-2}$, so $300\ \mathrm{W}\cdot\mathrm{m}^{-2}$ is 30% (at perpendicular insolation; don't forget to multiply with appropriate cosine as wings have to be approximately level to support the aircraft and the panels can't therefore be turned towards the Sun), which is actually pretty good efficiency. IIRC green plants manage only about 4%.

Comment: @JanHudec that's why I stated normal incidence and said I was being very optimistic. Could be clearer but...

Comment: @AEhere, sure. I mainly wanted to point out that the panels are mediocre sources because Sun does not provide that much in the first place, not because they would have poor efficiency.

Comment: @JanHudec I added that graph, but mostly because I do love throwing it at solar power fans :)

Comment: $C_{D0}$ is proportional to wetted area? Or is it a form factor, multiplied by the wing area?

Comment: @Koyovis you are right, it is a factor, it is the resultant parasitic contribution that scales with area.

Answer (score 4):

Adding chord to an existing wing does the following:

- It increases wing area S
- It reduces aspect ratio A
- It increases weight.

These three factors influence each other and should all be considered.

Drag D of a sub-sonic fixed wing aeroplane is
$$D = C_D \cdot \frac{1}{2}  \rho  V^2 \cdot S = \left( C_{D0} + \frac{{C_L}^2}{\pi  A e }\right)\cdot \frac{1}{2}  \rho  V^2 \cdot S \tag{1}$$

Lift L = weight W (a valid approximation at stationary flight at small angles):
$$L = W = C_L \cdot \frac{1}{2}  \rho  V^2 \cdot S => C_L = \frac{2 \cdot W}{\rho   V^2 \cdot S} \tag{2}$$

Substitute (2) into (1):
$$D =  C_{D0} \cdot \frac{1}{2}  \rho  V^2 \cdot S + \frac{2  W^2}{\pi  A e \cdot  \rho  V^2 \cdot S} \cdot \tag{3}$$

With:

- S = wing area
- A = aspect ratio = $b^2 / S$ with $b$ = wing span
- e = Oswald factor, accounting for varieties in profile drag, lift distribution, interference.

Substitute $A \cdot S = b^2$ in (3):

$$D =  C_{D0} \cdot \frac{1}{2}  \rho  V^2 \cdot S + \frac{2  W^2}{\pi e \cdot  \rho  V^2 \cdot b^2} $$

So now we can see what increasing chord does while keeping span the same

- It increases S with increasing chord
- It increases weight with increasing chord
- It decreases e with increasing chord
- It decreases $C_{D0}$ with increasing chord if only chord is added to the wing profile and thickness stays the same - relative thickness decreases and $c_d$ decreases. $C_{D0}$ remains the same if both chord and thickness are increased proportionally.

Three out of four factors above increase drag with weight being a quadratic factor, and we're hoping to offset the increase in drag with more propulsive power. We're increasing drag, weight, complexity, cost...

Prudent aircraft design would be contrary to this.

Comment: The simple answer is: If you add area, do it at the tips as well.

Comment: *"It decreases $C_{D0}$ with increasing chord"* I can't see that from the equation presented, it seems to me $C_{D0}$ is a coefficient multiplied by $S$. For an equal span an increase in chord will increase $S$ and thus the contribution of the parasite term.

Comment: @AEhere have added into the answer.

Comment: @Koyovis fair enough, I didn't think you were operating on the airfoil itself. The pedant in me does want to point out that this might not be a general solution: at low $Re$ adding to the chord may trip the boundary layer and raise drag, but I don't have any numbers handy to argue how much of an impact this has compared to the relative thickness reduction.

Comment: @Koyovis Wouldn't "S" and "weight" be increased no matter what? If the aircraft needs x amount of power to fly, and you need more solar cells to reach x, increasing the the span will still effect both these properties. I'm not familiar with how to solve for "e", but I guess the cord changes it enough to be significant?

Comment: @YAHsaves Weight is minimised very scrutinously. S is a major design parameter: W/S is the wing loading, which is determined in the pre-design, it is optimised for lowest drag. Lower weight, lower surface area and higher wing loading all decrease drag.

Comment: @Koyovis So basically the wing has a limited surface area to play with. Since increasing the span while keeping the cord the same would also increase "S" and weight. I guess what you're saying is we really need more efficient solar cells, instead of just trying to make the surface area larger somehow. Is that correct?

Comment: @YAHsaves Yes the wing surface area is optimised for minimal drag. The whole design is a multi-dimensional matrix with very many in- and outputs, with aerodynamic optimisation having adverse effects on constructional weight and vice versa. Unfortunately, a "just add water" approach doesn't work in aeronautical engineering.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely could add chord to the wings, but it is the same question of efficiency.  Rarely do you sacrifice aerodynamic efficiency to carry more weight.

But in this case the benefits of adding chord to increase surface area have merit, although keeping aspect ratio the same and simply making the whole wing bigger may be a choice as well.  And let's not forget the possibility of adding area to the tail too.

Another possibility is to scale up the size of the aircraft, as weight per surface area increases with size.  Improving the efficiency of the solar cells and the charge carrying capacity of the batteries also helps.

Also, take note of the span loading benefits of the NASA aircraft.  (a little more weight on the ends may have been an improvement)

Comment: Yes I agree you could scale everything up while keeping the dimensions proportional. However that has it's own problems, 1) longer spans are harder to store/find landing for ect.... 2) weight is a product of volume which is multiplied by 3 directions, while surface area is a product of 2 directions. Which means weight scales faster than surface area. So keeping the geometry the same, but scaling things up will get heavy. I guess I'm asking could you offset these potential negatives using the geometry proposed in my answer?

Comment: A wider wing is certainly stronger. And you can even consider 2 wings! Yes, lifting capacity would have to match weight, so greater chord and thicker scale up is possible.  Desired cruising speed is another very important consideration.

Comment: @YAHsaves a design you may look into is the RB-57 Canberra.